# RoboCopy gets stuck in a loop

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, robocopy

We use Robocopy via batch in Task Scheduler to mirror a folder on a local disk with a folder on a Web Server.

Staff add new images to the locak disk and then the Web Server is updated once RC detects changes.

It seems to work perfectly for random amounts of time, sometimes minutes sometimes days before eventually it goes haywire and assumes that all files are newer and then just continues to copy endlessly.

These are the current switches we are using

```
ROBOCOPY M:\images\ W:\images\ /copy:DAT /MIR /FFT /Z /MON:1 /XO /MOT:1 /XD     raw hi-res
```

We have tried all sorts of changes, most recently adding /XJ to exclude Junction Points but nothing works.

We've even made sure there is no time disparity between the two drives but they are both up to date and /FFT should take care of any small discrepancies.

Can anyone spot what we're missing? It's not the end of the world checking on it daily Mon-Fri but it's making our weekend lives hell as we have to keep RDP'ing in to fix when the weekend staff are working.

Comment: Apart from the fact there is little point in specifying the default, `/copy:DAT`, I'm not sure if it's wise to monitor for both a single change and also enforce a check every minute. How does the script perform with just one of those options?

Comment: Exactly the same sadly, however you're right I have killed one of the options just for the sake of being sensible.

Comment: What is the period at which the Task Scheduler invokes the batch?